# The PDF/CDF of the distance between a fixed point and a point uniformly distributed in a circle

Tags: probability

I have a geometrical probability described in the following, Thanks so much for your kind help!

**Question:**

As shown in the following figure, in the circle with radius $R$ and center $O$, $P$ is a fixed point and not the center of the circle, while $Q$ is a uniformly distributed point. $OP = p$, $OQ = x$ and $PQ = d$.

Then, how to obtain the PDF/CDF of the square of the distance between $P$ and $Q$? Namely, the PDF/CDF of $d^2 = x^2 - 2px\cos \theta + p^2$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since $P$ is arbitrary and fixed, we can WLOG consider it along the $x$-axis so your $p$ is fixed as well. Now you are choosing $x \in (0,R)$ and $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ or ($(0,2\pi)$ if you want to measure full angle not the shortest one). You need to specify their common distribution (e.g. both uniform and independent, or uniform in area etc) with some common pdf $f(x,\theta)$, and then, for example, you have
$$
\mathbb{E}[d^2] = \int_{x=0}^R \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} d^2(x,\theta) f(x,\theta) d\theta dx
$$
and you can compute cdf of $d^2$ in a similar way...

Comment: $\theta$ and $d$ are independently uniformly distributed, and $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$

Comment: @junxvpenn so use this to complete the problem then